# Visual Studio 2012 + NUnit => reports?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, reporting

Starting in VS 2012, the test adapter support has been extended to allow UTs other than MSTest to run *inside* the IDE. Which is awesome.

My question is: using the [NUnit test adapter](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapterReleaseNotes&r=2.6.2) to run my suite of NUnit UTs, how can I get a report of the results in a computer-readable format (i.e. xml)?
FWIW I run VS 2012 Professional.

I'd hate to have to fire the NUnit test runner GUI every time I need a report file.

Side question: did anybody running Resharper (7) successfully export the results of a sizable UT suite?
I have ~2500 UTs and the report (be it text or HTML) generated by Resharper stops abruptly at some point in the file.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: using the NUnit test adapter to run my suite of NUnit
>   UTs, how can I get a report of the results in a computer-readable
>   format (i.e. xml)?*

Yes, there is a feature called "PlayList"

Select all your tests, and right click - select Add to play List -> New Playlist. Save the file as .playlist file. Now you can Save As an xml file.

Comment: the keyword in my question was "report of the **results**". The playlist is just that - a list of tests. A subset of the available tests - it doesn't hold any info regarding the results of the test runs.

Comment: Ah yep, sorry I missed that.